# Is it possible to execute a CLTV transaction in bitoin core 0.11 console?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core, raw

The title says it all. How can one perform a op_checklocktimeverify transaction using bitcoin core? I've searched around and I've found a few repo's on github but nothing about how to do it in the console. I was thinking it would be something that you would just tack onto the end of a raw tx like this:

```
createrawtransaction '[{"txid":"","vout":}]' '{"receive_address":0.02}' '{"op_checklocktimeverify":desired_block_height}'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`OP_CHECKTIMELOCKVERIFY`is not currently implemented in Bitcoin Core and thus can not be used.

Comment: This is no longer correct, see below.

Answer (score 6):

`OP_CHECKTIMELOCKVERIFY` is implemented as of Bitcoin Core 0.11.2.

This release supports a soft fork to enable CLTV (BIP 65).  CLTV is part of version 4 blocks.  Once 951 blocks are mined with version 4 blocks, then the soft fork is complete on only version 4 blocks are valid from this point on.

You will need to construct the CLTV transaction using other software.  Here is an example that requires bitcore (NodeJS):

https://github.com/mruddy/bip65-demos

Comment: Been waiting for this. Any other resources out there that you are aware of other than NodeJS?

Comment: Just the Python implementation from the original proposal (BIP 65).  https://github.com/petertodd/checklocktimeverify-demos.